# What will this code look like in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems, I wrote code in Jquery, the worker asks not to use it. This function should check the inputs for fullness

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
      $('.registration__labels .rfield').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            console.log(2);
            $('input[required]').addClass('error');
        } else {
            console.log(1);
            $('input[required]').removeClass('error');
        }
      });
    });
});
```

here is the Jquery code, it works

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function validation (){
  if(btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ('.registration__labels .rfield').forEach(() => {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('input[type=text]').value == '') {
          console.log(2);
          (".input[required]").classList.add('error');
        }
        else {
          console.log(1);
          (".input[required]").classList.remove('error');
        }
      }
  )}))[validation]});
```

and this is me trying to translate it into javascript and it doesn't work. Help me pls

Comment: jquery IS javascript

Comment: the error is probably in using forEach

Comment: I'd say that `('.registration__labels .rfield')` is not at all what you may think it is ... hint, it's a string - also `if(btn.addEventListener` looks wrong ... since addEventListener returns undefined

Comment: Your coworker should have just told you what to fix. It's pretty clear what the issue is. Are they being passive-aggressive or something?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, `getElementsByClassName('input[type=text]')` makes absolutely zero sense, since `input[type=text]` is not likely to be a class

Comment: the code that uses jquery can be written like https://pastebin.com/nZYzAW0J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a way to do that...

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => 
  {
  const allRegLabs = document.querySelectorAll('.registration__labels .rfield')  

  document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = () =>
    {
    allRegLabs.forEach( el =>
      {
      let err =  el.classList.toggle('error', (el.value === ''))
      console.log( (err ? '2':'1' ))
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: You may have to do the query for "allRegLabs" from inside the event handler, that's what they did and it can have different results.